# how to get a week's date with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

i'm using autohotkey to work with date, i need to catch the day a week ago

example

if today is the 28th then I have to take the 21st of last week

[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zqyU.png)

in the following script I take the current date

```
FormatTime, date, , dd/MM/yyyy
MsgBox %date%
```

I even thought of a logic, to take the current day subtract by 7 that will take the day a week ago. I need help to create a better script

```
28 - 7 = 21
```

if anyone can help me thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtracting numbers would be bad when you encountered a change between months.
Would have to create custom logic for that.

Luckily AutoHotkey's `+=` operator supports [date/time math](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/EnvAdd.htm).
So this is all you need:

```
;we're starting off the date1 variable as blank,
;which means the current time will be used.
date1 += -7, days 
FormatTime, finalDate, % date1, dd/MM/yyyy ;format the result to our desired format
MsgBox, % finalDate
```

Comment: thank you friend, it worked. I made the script with my logic too, I will post for you to analyze

Comment: It has exactly the problem I mentioned in this answer. Try to subtract 28 or more days and you'll see. Also, assuming it would've been a good solution, you could've used the `A_DD`, `A_MM` and `A_YYYY` [variables](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#date) instead of FormatTime to get cleaner and more compact code.

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way

```
FormatTime, date_, , dd
sub += date_-7
FormatTime date, , /MM/yyyy
MsgBox,%sub%%date%
```